# Promoting Stack Exchange at CiviCon

Tags: discussion

I realize that the CiviCon schedule is almost finalized - and there's not a single reference on the schedule to Stack Exchange.  There's one last lightning talk session not claimed - does anyone want to take this and present on Stack Exchange?  Coleman and I are already doing lightning talks - so if there's someone who doesn't have one already, that'd be ideal.

Comment: Where can I view the list of Lightning talks? Joanne has been a big champion for this site and might not be presenting anything else.

Comment: We're publishing it tomorrow - but we filled all the spots.  I would give up my spot to Joanne for this though, who's not presenting otherwise!  I'll bring it up at the meeting tomorrow.

Comment: I'd also give up mine.

Comment: I did think about this, but unfortunately I don't arrive at Denver International until 5 minutes after the lightening talks begin, so your spots are safe Jon G and Coleman.

Comment: Goodness, you have to proof-read properly!  My spelling mistake will be forever visible. Perhaps it will teach me not to do two things at the same time.

Comment: I can switch my talk topic from the Api Explorer to StackExchange, I think the former can be covered in other places and the latter is more important to broadcast.

Comment: I submitted a lightning talk session proposal for you this morning Coleman; I'll change it.

Comment: @JoAnne a speling mistake on the internet? Unherd of!

Comment: same question for civiconlondon. is anyone going to talk about it already?